# How to write a regex of IP and exclude specific IP

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I need a validation of String which should follow IPv4 proxy pattern.
But 0.0.0.0(...) is not allowed

```
0.0.0.0/23(not match)
0.0.0.0/0(not match)
12.2.3.4/23(match)
13.2.3.53(match)
```

Currently I have regex to match (IP and IP proxy)

```
(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/\d+)?
```

But how could I exclude 0.0.0.0 or 0.0.0.0/...

Comment: Just start your regex with `^(?!0\.0\.0\.0/)`

Comment: ...unless the regex engine does not support lookarounds.

Comment: So which regex engine are you using here?

Comment: In bash environment @Jan

Comment: How could I add "AND" exclude lookarounds there. I tryed (?!(0\.0\.0\.0)) and ^(?!0\.0\.0\.0/) which is not work, I might make syntax error @anubhava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu grep` you can use a negative lookahead:

```
grep -P '^(?!0\.0\.0\.0/)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/\d+)?' file
12.2.3.4/23(match)
13.2.3.53(match)
```

Or else, you can use `awk` to exclude `0.0.0.0` like this:

```
awk -F/ '$1 != "0.0.0.0"' file

12.2.3.4/23(match)
13.2.3.53(match)
```

Comment: Could I combine them into one regex? My actual environment is Yang module. which is similar with bash regex. But awk is not supported

Comment: Yes I have provided a gnu grep with a single regex as well

Comment: Thanks you, (?!0\.0\.0\.0(\/\d+)?)(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/\d+)? seems work for me